# Map induced by fibrations is a fibration

Tags: model-categories

I have the following problem: given a model category $\mathcal{C}$ and an indexing set $I$ I have objects $X$ and $Y_i$ for every $i \in I$ with a fibration $f_i \colon X \rightarrow Y_i$. Now using the universal property of products defining a map $\phi \colon X \rightarrow \prod_i Y_i$ is the same as specifying some maps $X \rightarrow Y_i$. I take these maps to be the $f_i$ and I want to show that the induced map is itself a fibration. I can assume all the named objects are fibrant.

When I first considered this problem I thought I could adapt the usual argument that pull-backs and products preserve fibrations, i.e. I write down a square diagram with the left vertical map an acyclic cofibration and show there exists a diagonal lift by using the lifting properties of the maps involved in the construction of $\phi$ (which is obviously the vertical right map). But I cannot prove that the lifts obtained from the $f_i$ produce a lift in the diagram involving $\phi$.

Do you have any idea or a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the category $\mathbf{Top}$ of topological spaces and continuous maps. It has a closed model structure in which categorical fibrations are fibrations in the usual sense. Let $f_1, f_2 = id : X \to X$. These are fibrations and you obtain $\phi = $ diagonal map $X \to X \times X$. This is not a fibration which can be seen most easily for path-connected $X$ (all fibrations with a path-connected base must be surjective).

Comment: Really clear and concise. Thanks.